# How make Intellij do before launch actions when redeploy external artifact?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, deployment, ear

I build an artifact (ear) with maven and deploy it to a local WebSphere Application Server 8 with Intellij IDEA 15, so I configured "before launch" action "mvn clean package".

Intellij starts WAS and deplopyment goes well, but when I try to do a redeploy, maven begins to build the artifact but installation it to WAS goes in a parallel and fails, so when maven finishes there is no proper insalled applicaion and I have to run "deploy" in Intellij manually by clicking a green arrow using a mouse to get it run.

How can I tell Intellij wait for "before launch" tasks to be finished before it will do the redeploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I wrote a wsadmin script to redeploy the app and assigned the intellij idea shortcut to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [MultiRun](https://github.com/rkhmelyuk/multirun/wiki) plugin?

It completely solved my problem with launching/running multiple sub-tasks in sequence (or not in sequence if you choose) before the primary task is launched.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it but the "redeploy" (Ctrl+F10) action doesn't run maven at all, so I redeploying the same ear again, and I would like to tell Intellij to build it first with all "before launch" tasks I set.

Comment: if you make each step that you would like to take a separate intellij launch command, you should be able to accomplish what you want (since multirun can iterate over intellij launch commands)